# Is there anything wrong with this code

Tags: isr, cpp

Hi I'm pretty new to cpp.
Could someone review my code and explain any pitfalls or problems?
Below is the code and an example to read from a flow meter with a hall sensor.
Thanks in advance.
Greg

```cpp
    /** example
    #include "flow.h"
    Flow f(3);
    Flow f2(4);
    volatile unsigned int counter;
    void flow_counter() // ISR
    {
          // Increment the pulse counter
          counter ++;
    }
    
    void setup() 
    {
      f.start(); //using default ISR 
      f2.assign_isr(&flow_counter);
      f2.assign_counter(&counter);
      f2.start();
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
     Serial.printf("flow rate on 3 = %f \n",f.rate());
     Serial.printf("flow total = %dml %f%% of 500ml \n",f.total_ml(),f.percent(500));
     Serial.printf("flow rate on 4 = %f \n",f2.rate()); 
     delay(1000);
    }
    
    */
    
    
    #include <math.h>
    #include "Arduino.h"
    
    
    volatile unsigned int flowPulseCounter;
    void flowCounter() // ISR
    {
          // Increment the pulse counter
          flowPulseCounter ++;
    }
    
    class Flow{
      public:
        Flow(uint8_t pin)
        {
          if(flowPin==254)
           flowPin = pin;
        }
        
        void assign_isr ( void (*isr)()){ this->flowISR = isr; };
        void assign_counter (volatile unsigned int * counter ){ this->counter = counter; };
        void assign_pin(uint8_t pin){ flowPin = pin; };
        
        void  set_calibration_factor( float factor ) { this->calibrationFactor = factor; };
        float get_calibration_factor( ) { return this->calibrationFactor; };
        
        uint8_t retrieve_pin(){ return flowPin; };
        
        void start()
        {
          detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(this->flowPin));
          *this->counter = 0; // counter is a pointer so * assigns the value at that address to 0
          this->flowRate = 0;
          this->flowMillilitres = 0;
          this->flowMilliseconds = millis();
          pinMode(this->flowPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
          this->running = true;
          attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(this->flowPin), this->flowISR, FALLING);
        }
    
        void calculate()
        {
          if(this->running)
          {
            this->flowRate = ((1000.0 / (millis() - this->flowMilliseconds)) * ( *this->counter )) / this->calibrationFactor;
            this->flowMilliseconds = millis();
            // convert to millilitres.
            this->flowMillilitres = (this->flowRate / 60) * 1000;
            // Add the millilitres to the cumulative total
            this->totalMillilitres += this->flowMillilitres;
          }
        }
        
        void stop()
        {
          detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(flowPin));
          this->calculate();
          this->running = false;
          pinMode(this->flowPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        }
            
        bool is_max( uint32_t millilitres )
        {
          this->calculate();
          return (this->totalMillilitres >= millilitres) ? true : false;
        }
        
        float percent( uint32_t millilitres )
        {
          this->calculate();
          return (float)((double) this->totalMillilitres / (double) millilitres)  * 100.0;
        }
        
        float rate ()
        {
          this->calculate();
          return this->flowRate;
        }
        
        uint32_t total_ml()
        {
          this->calculate();
          return this->totalMillilitres;
        }        
            
      private:
        uint8_t flowPin=0;    
        uint32_t flowMilliseconds = 0;  
        float flowRate=0;
        uint32_t flowMillilitres = 0;
        uint32_t totalMillilitres = 0;
        float calibrationFactor = 4.5;
        bool running = false;
        void (*flowISR)() = &flowCounter;
        volatile unsigned int * counter = &flowPulseCounter;
    };
```

Comment: Why is the entire first section commented out?

Comment: @chrisl: It's a library. The comment block is an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I can see is in your use of the `counter` variable. This is a volatile variable that is incremented in an interrupt routine and read from the main loop context.  The variable is "non atomic" in that it is made up of a number of smaller bytes (at least on 8 bit Arduinos it is) which means it takes multiple sequential instructions to read it from memory.

At any point during that sequence the interrupt could trigger and modify the value, corrupting your data.

You should always use a *critical section* around any accesses to variables that are modified inside interrupt routines, such as:

```cpp
noInterrupts(); // Disable interrupts
uint32_t currentCount = this->counter; // Grab the current count
interrupts(); // Re-enable interrupts

// Do things with currentCount instead of this->counter
```

Comment: re:You should always use a critical section around any accesses to variables that are modified inside interrupt routines, such as:

As the variable is volatile and thus explicitly read every time why is this necessary. Killing the interrupts breaks so much other stuff.

Comment: Because, as I said, **it is not atomic**. That means that the variable can change *while it is being read because it is not one single operation but a sequence of smaller operations*.

Comment: And you always keep the critical section as short as possible so as to reduce the impact of temporarily disabling interrupts, which in this instance should be zero impact.

Comment: Sorry @Majenko I was rushing out to work and didn't read your comment properly.

Comment: Here is what I propose as a solution. I am happy to be wrong though.```            uint32_t this_count = count;
            uint32_t count_check = count;
            if((this_count>>3)!=(count_check>>3)
              return -0.0; // I like this return as it allows for valid 0 values to be returned as well 
            // valid read ie. all but the last 3 bits match allowing some advancement in the counter ```

Comment: While I understand your thinking I don't totally agree. 
Yes it may be correct for an 8bit single thread environment as are many AVRs it is not always the case.
I don't like the idea of having an interrupt disable section hidden inside a class. 
Working with the esp32 (ie. multiple cores and a very simple multi-thread system) the possibility of breaking many things increases. 
Also if I run several instances of the class they could interrupt each others counters.

Comment: @Yardie: 1. If you publish a library that only works on the ESP32, you should document this limitation, and have a conditional `#error` directive in the header that prevents anyone from using it on another platform. 2. This critical section is so tiny it will have no impact. If the pulses come so fast that it does have an impact, your program will be unable to process them anyway.

Comment: @Yardie It's not "my" thinking: critical sections have been around since the dawn of computing. Nothing in your question says you want to use an ESP32, and since this is the *Arduino* site we have to assume, unless you tell us otherwise, that you are using an Arduino. And since the majority of Arduino boards are 8 bits it's safe to assume that a critical section *will* be required. If your do happen to want to use some other board then you have to take the action appropriate to *that* board. For a 32-bit board it may well be that the operation is atomic and no action ...

Comment: ... is required. But of you want to publish your library for others to use you cannot assume that they will all want to use an ESP32. You will need to take appropriate steps to craft a suitable critical section for those boards that require them (all non-32 bit boards for sure, and maybe some 32-bit ones as well). For that defining your own macros that change depending on what is being compiled for will be useful. Also depending on the target architecture you may be able to use a more fine grained critical section whereby you only disable the interrupt that you are working with, rather ...

Comment: ... that disabling them globally. But in general, to allay your fears about critical sections, when interrupts are disabled any interrupts that would occur would generally be deferred until the interrupts are re-enabled again, at which point they will then be handled. And if your critical section is only a handful of clock cycles long and interrupts only occur with thousands of clock cycles between them then the impact of the critical section is going to be non-existent.

Comment: Ok thanks guys.

Comment: Yes you are right however code for Arduino now needs to consider the ESP. I am working with both and write code primarily for myself. If I was to publish the code this post is the only place I would publish it. I have gained a lot from free software and like to put back when I can. That's all. I love my ATTinies and want to write something that works for both. I was simply trying to cover both possibilities. Stopping the whole interrupt system to read a variable has always bothered me. However reading your last comment Majenko that does allay this and clarify my misconception

Comment: I have investigated enough low level code to see some rather nasty assumptions and oversights. I wanted to avoid that in my code even if it is just for me.

Comment: Anyway thanks heaps everyone your help has been fantastic and very enlightening. Sorry if I have offended anyone in any way. It was never intended. No one was born with this knowledge and we all travel different paths. Thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Edgar I could never publish this code anyway. It's basically your code now anyway. :) Thanks. I now have a simple library to easily add a flow meter to an attiny or an esp32. That's all I wanted. Oh and a deeper understanding of the issues involved as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some random comments from looking at the code.

First issue, which is more about the example than the library itself:
there is no `Serial.printf()` in the standard Arduino cores. Yes, it is
provided by some alternate cores, and it is a shame it is not available
in the Arduino ones, but that's how it is.

In the constructor, there is `if(flowPin==254)`. Why this condition?
`flowPin` is initialized to zero, so it would seem the condition should
always be false.

As a matter of style, you can remove all the `this->` from the methods.
It is implicit anyway.

For the sake of naming consistency, I would rename `retrieve_pin()` as
`get_pin()`, and all the `assign_*()` method as `set_*()`.

It is not useful to `detachInterrupt()` right before
`attachInterrupt()`, as the latter implies the former.

In `calculate()`, avoid calling `millis()` twice. You have no guarantee
that both calls will return the same value and, if they do not, the
timing calculations will be off. Also, this function will fail badly
(division by zero) if called twice within the same millisecond.

It makes no sense to convert a flow rate to milliliters. Do you mean
milliliters per minute? Per second? In any case, you here converting a
rate to another unit, but it is still a flow rate.

The computation of `totalMillilitres` is wrong: it is incremented by a
flow rate. It should instead be incremented by a product rate × time. Or
better yet: compute it from the pulse count, without going through the
rate. Otherwise you are computing a numerical derivative (to get the
rate) only to integrate it later (to get a total volume). This extra
computations serve no purpose other than accumulating rounding errors.

---

**Edit**: Thinking further about this program, I found a few more things
that I think could be improved. A couple of minor points an one not so
minor.

One of the minor points is that `begin()` would be a better name for
`start()`, for consistency with most other Arduino libraries.

Another one is that there are a couple of methods that have no business
being in the class: `is_max()` and `percent()`. They are trivial
calculations that are in no way related to handling a flow meter. As a
user of the library, I would rather write

```cpp
if (flow.total_ml() >= threshold_volume) ...
```

than

```cpp
if (flow.is_max(threshold_volume)) ...
```

as the former is way clearer and easy to understand.

The more serious point is about the handling of multiple flow meters.
The first one is completely handled by the library, which is nice.
However, for the second one, the user has to provide the lowest level
bricks. The user of a library should not have to handle himself such
low-level details. Thus, I think both the counter variable and the ISR
function should be handled by the library, as members of the `Flow`
class.

I am aware this creates some difficulties. In order to be attached to an
interrupt, the ISR should be a static method of the class. In order for
this method to access the counter, that counter should be a static
member. In order for each flow meter to have its own counter, we must
have a separate class for each one.

I found a solution that I think is elegant enough: have `Flow` be a
*class template*, parametrized by the pin number. This creates a
separate class for each flow meter. In order to avoid code duplication,
these classes could be almost empty shells that delegate as much as
possible to a handler which is a common, regular class.

Here is what that “handler” class could look like. It has everything
but the ISR:

```cpp
class FlowMeterHandler {
    // Everything here is private, only accessible to the Flow class.
    template<uint8_t pin> friend class Flow;
private:
    void begin(uint8_t pin, void (*isr)()) {
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), isr, FALLING);
    }
    float flow_rate() {
        uint32_t now = millis();
        if (now - last_millis >= 10) {
            uint32_t this_count;
            noInterrupts();
            this_count = count;
            interrupts();
            last_flow = calibration * (this_count - last_count)
                                    / (now - last_millis);
            last_millis = now;
            last_count = this_count;
        }
        return last_flow;
    }
    // + other methods...
    volatile uint32_t count = 0;
    uint32_t last_count = 0;
    uint32_t last_millis = 0;
    float last_flow = 0;
    float calibration = 1e3 / 4.5;
};
```

I've written the methods inline, but you could also put the
implementations in a separate .cpp file.

And here is the template class. Save for the ISR, it forwards everything
to the handler.

```cpp
template<uint8_t pin> class Flow {
public:
    static void begin() { handler.begin(pin, isr); }
    static float flow_rate() { return handler.flow_rate(); }
    // other methods also forwarded to the handler...
private:
    static FlowMeterHandler handler;
    static void isr() { handler.count++; };
};

template<uint8_t pin> FlowMeterHandler Flow<pin>::handler;
```

Note that the class has no instance data: everything in it is `static`.

Here is how this would be used:

```cpp
Flow<3> f1;
Flow<4> f2;

void setup()
{
    f1.begin();
    f2.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print(F("flow rate on 3 = "));
    Serial.println(f1.flow_rate());
    Serial.print(F("flow rate on 4 = "));
    Serial.println(f2.flow_rate());
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have to go to work now but will check this properly after. Thanks Edgar

Comment: Edgar this is gorgeous very elegant. I still don't like the 

```c++ 
noInterrupts();
this_count = count;
interrupts();
```

Comment: the if(flowPin==254) was left over from an earlier attempt at multiple instances which I didn't finish fleshing out sorry that was a red herring

Comment: I also like your thinking with```if (flow.total_ml() >= threshold_volume)``` makes everything very simple.

Comment: @Yardie: Re “_I still don't like the `noInterrupts(); ...`_”: avr-gcc has the [`ATOMIC_BLOCK()` macro](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html) which encapsulates this interrupt masking in an arguably semantically clearer way. It is, however, AVR-specific, and thus not suitable in a wider Arduino context. AFAIK, the Arduino core provides nothing better than `noInterrupts()`/`interrupts()` for atomic access to variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if anyone is interested here is what I ended up with

```cpp
/*
  this is yet to be varified but comes from the following links
  * 
  https://www.bc-robotics.com/tutorials/using-a-flow-sensor-with-arduino/ 
  
  "These are not able to monitor a flow of less than 1 liter per minute or in excess of 30 liters per minute.
  The sensor is rated to a Maximum of 2.0MPa (290 PSI) "
  and   
  every rotation means 2.25mL of fluid has passed the sensor

  another is 

  https://diyhacking.com/projects/FlowMeterDIY.ino
  "// The hall-effect flow sensor outputs approximately 4.5 pulses per second per
   // litre/minute of flow.
  "
  
  then finally 
  
  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/84578/is-there-anything-wrong-with-this-code
  
  I make no personal claim to any of this code. It is simply my version of Edgar's version. 
  Thanks Edgar
  * 
  * 
  * 
  * I have used start and stop as they signify the start and stop of the process 
  * the class begins when it starts and has no end the isr stays linked to the class for the duration 
  * and start simply attaches the interrupt to the isr 
  * stop simply calculates the total volume and detaches the interrupt.
  * 
  * as flow rate related to time 
  * just set your own start time 
  * read the total_ml
  * then after your own predefined time
  * read the total_ml again 
  * and work out the flow rate from that.
  */


class FlowMeterHandler {
  // Everything here is private, only accessible to the Flow class.
  template<uint8_t pin> friend class Flow;
private:
  
  void start(uint8_t pin, void (*isr)()) 
  {
    noInterrupts();
    count = 0;
    interrupts();
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), isr, FALLING);
  }
  
  void stop(uint8_t pin)
  {
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin));
  }
  
  unsigned int count_is()
  {
    unsigned int this_count;
    noInterrupts();
    this_count = count;
    interrupts();
    return this_count;
  }
  
  volatile unsigned int count = 0;
  unsigned int ul_per_tick = 2250;
  
};


template<uint8_t pin> class Flow {
public:
    static void start() { handler.start(pin, isr); }
    static void stop() { handler.stop(pin); }
    static unsigned int total_ul() { return handler.count_is() * handler.ul_per_tick; }
    static unsigned int total_ml() { return ( handler.count_is() * handler.ul_per_tick ) / 1000 ; }
    static void set_ul_per_rotation( unsigned int ul) { handler.ul_per_tick = ul; }
private:
    static FlowMeterHandler handler;
    static void isr() { handler.count++; };
};

template<uint8_t pin> FlowMeterHandler Flow<pin>::handler;
```

the example ino looks like this

```cpp
#include "flow.h"
Flow<3> f1;
Flow<4> f2;

void setup()
{
    f1.start();
    f2.start();
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print(F("So far volume on 3 = "));
    Serial.println(f1.total_ml());
    Serial.print(F("and the volume on 4 = "));
    Serial.println(f2.total_ml());
    delay(1000);
}
```

Compiles cleanly on all my boards.
Runs ???
Any other suggestions will be gratefully received.

Thanks.
Greg

Comment: Note that it is not useful to store `total_ml` inside `FlowMeterHandler`, as it is only ever used right after being set. That could instead be a local variable of `ml()`, or even be removed altogether: `float ml() { return count_is() * ml_per_tick; }` Also, it is not useful to call `ml()` from `stop()`.

Comment: Edgar thanks yep you are totally correct. They were unfinished/unnecessary ideas. Don't like redundant code either. I guess I've gotten sloppy self debugging for so long. These are the things I usually find months/years later. Why the hell did I do that? I have asked myself many times. Nice to have someone looking over my shoulder for a change. I changed the code tosuit.

Comment: probably could have just done ```return handler.count_is() * handler.ml_per_tick;``` in the template.

Comment: getting rid of the floats could speed it up a little. Using microlitres instead of ml.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without any description of the actual problem.

On the top of my head, with that much code i'd consider starting off by creating a separate class declaration, and write your member definitions outside. It will make the code way more manageable, and easier to troubleshoot.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/class-code-and-header-files/

Also, you have several include statements in at least two different places. They usually go first in a file, along with include guards. If your code consists of separate files, please make that clear to readers.

Comment: Re: the includes - I thought that at first too, until I noticed the first includes are inside a big comment.

Comment: I see it now. How do you make the snazzy color formatting, by the way?

Comment: You wrap it in something I can't type here ;) - backtick-backtick-backtick-c++ and backtick-backtick-backtick

Comment: I added the language specifier after the tripple-ticks in the question.  Seemed to have tripped enough people.  Sometimes without it the system doesn't syntax highlight or chooses the wrong language type.  You can see in the difference in the [edit history](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/84578/revisions).

Comment: \`\`\`c++ \[code\]\`\`\`

Comment: Excellent that is exactly the sort of answers I was after thankyou. The static ISR issue was particularly anoying to me.

Comment: @Erik sorry I thought the  /** example part and having it commented out would make it clear enough

Comment: Thank you @timemage for adding the language specifier. It certainly helps clarify the question